# How to calculate phonon decay rate?

Tags: condensed-matter, phonons, fermis-golden-rule

[Here](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1211.0450)<sup>1</sup>, the authors calculate the **quality factor** for a resonator. They take it as one over **phonon decay rate**, given by (24).
Simplified, (24) looks like this:
\begin{equation}
\Gamma = \gamma_{N-1,N} - \gamma_{N+1,N}
\end{equation}

$\Gamma$ is the phonon decay rate for a certain mode. Here $\gamma_{i,j}$ is Fermi golden rule transition rate from state with $i$ to $j$ phonons of the chosen mode ($\gamma_{i,j}=\gamma_{j,i}$ in our case; $\gamma_{j,i}\neq 0$ if $|i-j|=1$). Transitions happen due to phonon-electron scattering.

My questions are:

- **How can I obtain this rate?**
- **Are there other ways to define the decay rate?**

One guess would be:
\begin{equation}
\Gamma = (leaving) - (entering) = \left[N\gamma_{N,N-1} + N\gamma_{N,N+1} \right] - \left[(N-1)\gamma_{N-1,N} + (N+1)\gamma_{N+1,N} \right]=\gamma_{N-1,N} - \gamma_{N+1,N}
\end{equation}

But this way does not seem correct to me. It could be correct if $\gamma$ were the rate of decay of a single phonon.  For instance, $N\gamma_{N,N-1}$ stands here for the transition rate from $N$ to $(N-1)$, but the same rate from the golden rule is just $\gamma_{N, N-1}$ itself without any factors.

Can anyone explain how such things are calculated? I appreciate your help.

References:

1. Ze'ev Lindenfeld & Ron Lifshitz, "Damping of mechanical vibrations by free electrons in metallic nanoresonators", [*Phys. Rev. B* **87**, 085448 (2013)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.87.085448), [arXiv:1211.0450](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1211.0450).

Comment: Are you asking how to get $\gamma$ from Fermi's golden rule, or how to get their expression for $\Gamma$? (Or both.)

Comment: How to get $\Gamma$

Comment: Could you further explain your issue with their equation 24? (I'm getting confused by your translation, so I'd rather discuss their equation.) Is the issue that they're only considering transitions to states with +/-1 phonon?

Comment: Well, in general, my question was how they constructed that equation. In particular, why the two terms are the rates at which phonons leave the state and enter it. It may be something really simple but not obvious to me. Sorry for confusing you.